# Does Google AdSense ban ban every site under an account if one is found to violate the content policies?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I want to know that will one AdSense-banned site ban overall Adsense account or just the one site.

If one site gets banned for violating the Google AdSense content policies could it affect the other sites under the same account? eg. Pirated content if found in one domain will ban overall AdSense account, even though other sites are authentic.